# How to get all the versions of a particular FHIR resource in AWS FHIR store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, version, hl7-fhir

Is there a way to get the list of all the versions of a specific resource created in FHIR store. I have used the following call,

```
   <FHIR_URL>/<resource-type>/<resource-id>/_history
```

but its not returning response

If I add version to this url:

```
   <FHIR_URL>/<resource-type>/<resource-id>/_history/<version>
```

then it only shows that particular version of the resource, but all the versions of a specific resource are required, is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, I always try the reference-implementations.

(all GET requests below)

```
http://wildfhir4.aegis.net/fhir4-0-1/Patient/example/_history

https://vonk.fire.ly/R4/Patient/pat1/_history

http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient/616330/_history?_count=50
```

I got each systems Patient-Fhir-Logical-Id ("example", "pat1", "616330") by using the search function, and picking a random Patient.  The Search function is as simple as /Patient/? and no query string values.

While always subject to change and "re doing the seed data", the aegis example above (today) is returning multiple rows of history for a single patient.

If AWS does not work "mostly the same" as the 3 reference implementations, I would submit a bug report.

But based on your examples, it seems to fall in line with the reference implementation examples above and the HL7 documentation below.

https://build.fhir.org/http.html#history